# LangChain Downloading data from youtube

Tags: youtube, artificial-intelligence, openai-api, langchain, py-langchain

[Im downloading data from youtube but facing an issue how can i fix it ?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kit87.png)

i downloaded ffmpeg and set path to envirnment variable but didn't work
loading data from youtube throug langchian documentloader see image to get more

Answer (score 0):

It seems it's using yt_dlp.

Normally yt_dlp takes this path from command line argument --ffmpeg_location.

You can try one of the following:

- pass path to ffmpeg in --ffmpeg_location command line argument
- add ffmpeg dir PATH to PATH environment variable
- directly adjust parameters of langchain's parser instance of YoutubeAudioLoader

it's defaults are as follows:

```
        ydl_opts = {
            "format": "m4a/bestaudio/best",
            "noplaylist": True,
            "outtmpl": self.save_dir + "/%(title)s.%(ext)s",
            "postprocessors": [
                {
                    "key": "FFmpegExtractAudio",
                    "preferredcodec": "m4a",
                }
            ],
        }
```

you need to change postprocessors section to look like this:

```
  "postprocessors": [
                {
                    "key": "FFmpegExtractAudio",
                    "preferredcodec": "m4a",
                    "ffmpeg_location": "path_to_ffmpeg"

                }
```

- directly set parameter of ffmpegpostprocessor instance

```
from yt_dlp.postprocessor import FFmpegPostProcessor
FFmpegPostProcessor._ffmpeg_location.set(R'C:\...')
```